# OEM Installation problem (OEM option missing)

Tags: oem

I'm trying to figure out why the oem option is missing from different distributions of ubuntu(tried 12.04 and 14.04).Tried also with left shift key during boot but when i press F4 key(mode),i can see only the "normal" option.Am i doing something wrong here?Is there any available image for oem installation only ?Thank you in advance

Comment: i found the same exact problem but unfortunately with no answer... http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2101051

Answer (score -1):

Try booting to UEFI mode on boot of the computer (not the so) press the specific key to open the boot menu. From here select UEFI mode. That should get the options you need.